# Alert box is not visible

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-alertdialog

I am having an activity which checks for location changes and it shows an alert box if there is no location change for about 1 minitue. The problem that i am facing is that, if i am working on another activity the alert box of first activity is not visible to me. I can only see the alert box if I go back to previous activity. Is there any way to display an alert box from an activity in back ground to appear over other active activities. Kindly help me to find a solution.

This is the method that i am using to display alert box

```
public void alerter(String msg)
    {
      AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Location_Tracker_Individual_Service_Providers.this);
      builder.setMessage(msg)
             .setTitle("Warning!")
                         .setNegativeButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                 public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                      dialog.cancel();
                 }
             });

    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();
    }
```

Comment: Post the code. Without seeing code, it is hard to predict what is going on.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps create another class, with the set of alert functions(this class being global in a manner or in the parent activity). Calling the functions in this class from child activities should allow you to display them whenever required. Another option would be to create the alert in both activities and linking them, so that when the first is called it calls the second.

Comment: @lan: Can you explain the first method?

Comment: @lan: Kindly tell me, if i am making it global and activity1 (activity in back ground) is calling this alert box and currently i am working with activity 2, will this alert box appear over activity 2?